# Angular bootstrap typeahead not working with Angular 1.3.0

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I have created a small plunker to show that this is not working.  Can anyone please help me how to use typeahead with 1.3.0 angularJS /provide alternate solutions. We are using it with angular-bootstrap 0.11.0 and the latest version of bootstrap. Our code heavily relies on ng-messages introduced in 1.3.0

[Here is the plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/mBs59czqFBofPqbS0GKB)

As you can clearly see, the click events, up arrows and down arrows dont work. Adding some code to make SO happy. :)

```
 <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
      <h4>Static arrays</h4>
      <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
      <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" />

    </div>
```

Comment: angular.js version `1.3.0-beta.10` seems to work fine, could you downgrade to use that version instead?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2293

Comment: Aren't odd numbered versions of Angular not intended for production use?

Comment: @JMK That's no longer true, they started to adopt semver convention in 1.3 see this [blog](http://blog.angularjs.org/2013/12/angularjs-13-new-release-approaches.html). However, yes, all the 1.3.x are unstable, but OP want to use ng-messages so he must take a risk.

Comment: Thanks @JMK and runTarm for pointing and confirming. We are a little brave to use 1.3, but we like it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have three choices currently:

1. Downgrade angular.js version to `1.3.0-beta.10`

   The bug is caused by this `ngIf` fixed [d71df9](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/d71df9f83cd3882295ca01b1bb8ad7fb024165b6) which is landed in `1.3.0-beta.11`
2. Downgrade angular-bootstrap version to `0.10.0`

   The `typeahead` directive has started to use `ngIf` in `0.11.0`, so downgrade to `0.10.0` will also works.
3. Wait for angular-bootstrap `0.12.0`

   There is already an open issue [#2474](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2474) , it's planned to be fixed in `0.12.0`

**EDIT:** It seems the issue has been fixed by this commit [a0be450d](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/a0be450ddb7fff556b5fa4a0c2ddcbbe43588dc8) and landed in `0.11.2`.

Comment: 1.3.0-beta.10 - Thanks a ton. This was driving me nuts, I could not downgrade to 0.10.0 as it had a modal bug. :)

Comment: THANKS! I was at version `1.1.1` could not understand what was going on, I downgraded to `0.12.0` and it's working now.